# Find Object in Array Cross Multiple Properties

Tags: javascript

So I am playing around trying to build an input that I can type and then show only the objects that have matching text. I am getting close but need a little help. I think what I did works but I believe there might be a better way.

So I would expect that a user, in the input could type the following values:

- phone
- email
- firstName
- lastName
- firstName lastName

I think the code I have works for it all, but not sure I like what I did for first and last name. I wonder if I should be using regex instead of what I am doing. Thoughts?

```js
export let customers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    email: 'john.smith@test.com',
    phone: '7025551234',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Jonathan',
    lastName: 'Harken',
    email: 'jonathan.harken@test.com',
    phone: '7165551234',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Zack',
    lastName: 'Moss',
    email: 'zack.moss@test.com',
    phone: '9995551234',
  },
];

export const filterList = (suggestions, searchValue) => {
  return suggestions.filter((sug) => {
    let shouldReturn = false;

    for (const [key, keyValue] of Object.entries(sug)) {
      if (key !== 'id') {
        let keyV = keyValue.toLowerCase();
        let hasSpace = searchValue.indexOf(' ') > -1;

        if (!hasSpace && keyV.indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
          shouldReturn = true;
        }

        if (hasSpace) {
          let split = searchValue.split(' ');

          switch (key) {
            case 'firstName':
              if (keyV.indexOf(split[0]) > -1) {
                shouldReturn = true;
              }

              break;
            case 'lastName':
              if (keyV.indexOf(split[1]) > -1) {
                shouldReturn = true;
              }

              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (shouldReturn) {
      return sug;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

I just think something is off.

[image]

Comment: `indexOf` to look for static pieces of text is perfectly fine. Only improvement I could see a regular expression bringing here, is that you can make the whole search case-insensitive by just setting the according flag. (But that’s something you can have with indexOf as well, if you lowercase both input text and search value first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler version should behave like your function.

```js
let customers = [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    email: 'john.smith@test.com',
    phone: '7025551234',
},
{
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Jonathan',
    lastName: 'Harken',
    email: 'jonathan.harken@taest.com',
    phone: '7165551234',
},
{
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Zack',
    lastName: 'Moss',
    email: 'zack.moss@test.com',
    phone: '9995551234',
},
];


function filterByValue(objectList, searchValue) {

    const tokens = searchValue.toLowerCase().split(' ');

    return Object.values(objectList).filter(entry => {
        return Object.values(entry).some(entryValue => {

            if (typeof(entryValue) !== 'string')
                return false;
            
                entryValue = entryValue.toLowerCase();

            return tokens.every(token => entryValue.includes(token));
        })
    })
}

console.log(filterByValue(customers, '.com'))
console.log(filterByValue(customers, '555 234'))
console.log(filterByValue(customers, 'John 555'))
console.log(filterByValue(customers, 'John test .com'))
```